# Upgrade to 20.04 from 19.10 isn't available

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I upgraded from 18.04 to 19.10 some months ago and now I want to upgrade to 20.04. But `update-manager -c` doesn't show the new Ubuntu release 20.04.

Isn't the upgrade ready yet? Is it possible to upgrade to 20.04 from 19.10 now?

Answer (score 23):

I found this note in [How To Upgrade Ubuntu To 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa - LinuxConfig.org](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-20-04-lts-focal-fossa)

> **PLEASE NOTE**
>   Upgrades from 19.10 will not be enabled until a few days after 20.04's release. Upgrades from 18.04 LTS will not be enabled until a few days after the 20.04.1 release expected in late July 2020. There are no offline upgrade options for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server.

I have to wait some days. Hopefully works!

Comment: My KUbuntu 19.10 never updated to this LTS normally. Even after 6 days. I had to do `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` and it worked fine :)

Comment: My Kubuntu 19.10 hasn't either upgraded. I'm wondering if I should wait a little longer, or do the -d option.

Comment: I found out a page explaining all steps in case you try "sudo do-release-upgrade -d". All you need to do is: sudo apt install update-manager-core. set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades. sudo do-release-upgrade -d More details are here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-lts-using-command-line/

Comment: How many days is few days? It is May 5 and still no prompt for update.

Comment: Unfortunately the few days are extended to few months "July 2020" when the 20.04.1 release will be available. Before that only the development release is available:  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#3-check-for-updates. Ubuntu community should be more explicit next time when they launch a new release.

Comment: We were working to fix a bug with the upgrade process to 20.04 which has now been resolved and users of Ubuntu 19.10 will be prompted to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Only users of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will need to wait until July to be prompted to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Hi Brian, I trusted the community and went ahead with the upgrade. Unfortunately everything went wrong! The computer is not able to boot into Ubuntu, other booting are fine. I m running to fix this issue booting from USB flash drive which is time consuming. I would not recommend upgrading now, I think the release is still unstable. Once I fix the issue I will post it for those people running in the same trouble.

Comment: @BrianMurray Did you enable the upgrade yet? It still didn't show up for me.

Comment: This is the first time I recall upgrades for LTS being delayed for months, why?

Comment: I got it!! I did it from the terminal with sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop

Answer (score 5):

If you want to upgrade early then you can use

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

on kubuntu or

```
update-manager -d
```

for a new development release.