# i'm not able to upgrade my server running ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04. How do I upgrade?

Tags: 18.04, server, upgrade, 20.04

I am running a VPS that has Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I was able to upgrade it to 19.10 by setting `prompt=normal` in the `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file.
I set it back to LTS and tried updating to the 20.04 LTS release, but it doesn't seem to detect it.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the "Final Release" a "Development Release"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229890/is-the-final-release-a-development-release)

Comment: You can't upgrade VPS servers this way. The provider should do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [new Ubuntu 20.04 release does not show up in update-manager-c or](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230106/new-ubuntu-20-04-release-does-not-show-up-in-update-manager-c-or)